# With the Python Coinbase API, how do I figure out my pricing tier (fees)?

Tags: python, coinbase-api

I'm using the Python API for Coinbase Pro -- https://github.com/danpaquin/coinbasepro-python.  Is there a programmatic way I can calculate what pricing tier I'm in prior to submitting an order?  I would like to get an idea of the fees before I place the order.  I notice the authenticated client provides a way to get accounts

```
accts = auth_client.get_accounts()
```

which returns accounts that look like the below

```
{'id': 'f3af2ff9-15a9-4b09-bdce-2136baf413e1', 'currency': 'USD', 'balance': '6637.7288007189954500', 'hold': '
2003.9996462765652000', 'available': '4633.72915444243025', 'profile_id': 'cc15c482-e394-40a9-b183-6f456a67b188
', 'trading_enabled': True}
```

However their documentation suggests pricing tiers/fees are calculated based on trading volume, and I'm not sure a good way to programmatically figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the python api specifically but the exchange api does have a fees end point which looks at the trailing 30 day trade volume.

if the python api doesn't have a hook for this, you can do it directly. You'll just have to understand how to sign the request (the value for `"cb-access-sign":`) which is the bigger issue usually.

https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/fees

install requests

```
$python -m pip install requests
```

code sample

```
import requests
url = "https://api.exchange.coinbase.com/fees"
headers = {
 "Accept": "application/json",
 "cb-access-key": "<your key>",
 "cb-access-passphrase": "<your passphrase>",
 "cb-access-sign": "<your signing hash>",
 "cb-access-timestamp": "<timestamp used in signing hash>"
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: Actually seems the Python API's AuthenticatedClient method does have a "get_fees" implementation if installed with "pip install git+git://github.com/danpaquin/coinbasepro-python.git".

Answer (score 0):

First, you may want to review the information you just posted as it seems there may be sensitive data contained within the post. I'm not certain because I'm not familiar with the coinbase api.

Second, I'm pretty sure you can find a chart with the price-fee pairs in it. See the link below.

https://help.coinbase.com/en/coinbase/trading-and-funding/pricing-and-fees/fees

Comment: Hack away!  I saw the chart but my question was around how to do it with the Python API.